# How to filter on another class property with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have following classes

> ```
> EntityOne
> - Property1 : string
> - Property2 : int
> - Property3 : Array of EntityTwo
>
> EntityTwo
> - Property1 : string
> - Property2 : int
> ```

I want to write a `NSPredicate` which filters on `EntityTwoObj.property1` when I perform it on an array which holds `EntityOne` objects.

Is it possible?

I have tried following:

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"Property1 CONTAINS[cd] %@ 
OR Property2 CONTAINS[cd] %@ 
OR Property3.Property1 CONTAINS[cd] %@", 
newString, newString, newString];
```

But it's not working.

If I removed the last filter, it's working fine then.

Comment: You may need a `ANY` or `IN` for the last one.

Comment: @Larme, thank you so much, it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Larm, I could solved it by adding `ANY` operator with my predicate.

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"Property1 CONTAINS[cd] %@ 
OR Property2 CONTAINS[cd] %@ 
OR ANY Property3.Property1 CONTAINS[cd] %@", 
newString, newString, newString];
```